# Connect to db2 database with php 7.1.8 using xampp on windows

Tags: php, windows, xampp, db2

I have a problem. I am trying to query the db2 database with php 7 on Windows. So I have read a lot about connecting to db2 etc, and I have tried a lot of things and still I have the problem.

This is php.ini file:

```
extension=php_ibm_db2.dll
```

And this is an error I get every time:

```
[05-Oct-2017 13:44:55 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_ibm_db2.dll' - The specified module could not be found. in Unknown on line 0
```

I have tried both versions thread safe and non thread safe, but I can't get it to work.

I have done it with the php version 5.5.38 but I would like to use the latest one.

Additional information: 
I am running the windows 10 64bit.
I have downloaded 1.9.9 dll from the pecl library.
I have put it in the php.ini where all the other extensions are and in the following folder described down:
Of course there is the file in the `php\ext\php_ibm_db2.dll`

I am the administrator, so permissions are full.

Please if you have some solutions tell me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question to answer (1) which Windows version and bitness (2) how did you install the ibm_db2 module and (3) which version of that ibm_db2 module is installed

Comment: Is there a file `C:\xampp\php\ext\php_ibm_db2.dll` and if so, what are its permissions?

Comment: Is your php a 64-bit or 32-bit?  Is the ibm_db2 extension matching in bitness with both your php and your Db2 client ?  Looks like your PHP extensions directory differs from the location where xampp extensions are located.

Comment: @mao This is the folder that has all the extensions: C:\xampp\php\ext and my php is x86. I have downloaded the extension from here :  https://pecl.php.net/package/ibm_db2/1.9.9/windows

Comment: So a 32-bit PHP 7.1.8, with a 32-bit ibm_db2 pre-built v1.9.9 extension. Can you get the command-line PHP working with ibm_db2? (i.e. without using xampp, just to see if the basic environment works)?

Comment: @mao When I try to run the php.exe I get this error  `Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'D:\xampp\php\ext\php_pdo_ibm_5_3_vc9_ts.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0` I really don't have any more ideas.

Comment: Do you have the VC9 x86 redistributables installed (VC++ 2008 redistributable) ?  There may be some DLL dependencies in php_pdo_ibm.dll  , you can check this with the depends.exe that is downloadable from microsoft.